# how to use loop to get values in dir()?

Tags: python, dir

Why i can't get the values in the items in dir() with loop:

```
for item in dir():
    print(item)
```

It just print

```
 __builtins__
 __doc__
 __loader__
 __name__
 __package__
 __spec__
```

So, how can i use loop to print the value in item, i.e `"__main__"` in  `__name__`
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) without the argument is logically equivalent to `list(locals())`, as in getting the list of names of variables in the current namespace (*keys* of `locals()` dictionary).

You'd use the `items` method of `locals()` instead:

```
In [5]: for name, value in list(locals().items()):
   ...:     print(name, value)
   ...:
```

Answer (score 4):

vaultah's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379124/21945) is best, I think, but you could also use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) to get the values:

```
for item in dir():
    print('{} : {}'.format(item, eval(item)))
```

There is usually a lot of stigma regarding the use of `eval` ([it's dangerous!](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)) and I will probably be downvoted for this answer, however, I think that it OK in this limited case.

Comment: *I will probably be downvoted for this answer* ... Why? You've just provided an alternative ... :)